# Help me understand how $x^4-x^2$ was factored into $x^2(x+1)(x-1)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factoring

In a Khan Academy course there was a problem that required factoring.
They gave the answer but they skipped a step as to how this part was factored.

$$x^4-x^2 = x^2(x+1)(x-1)$$

I don't understand where the $+1$ and $-1$ came from and nothing makes sense except for me partly being able to see $x^2$ was factored out.
I also put the left side of it in an online equation calculator and it jumped straight to the part on the right. I'm not understanding how you get one from the other.

Comment: Can you factorize $x^2 - 1$? If yes, what will it be? If no, do you know the quadratic formula?

Comment: The point is that $x^2-1=(x-1)(x+1)$, as you can confirm by multiplying out the right hand .

Comment: @lulu it looks like x^2-1 should be (x)(x-1). I know it's not, but I don't understand where the +1 comes from.

Answer (score 2):

Start from the factorization
$$a^2-b^2=(a+b)(a-b)$$
which holds for every numbers $a$ and $b$. Then take $a=x$ and $b=1$. You get
$$x^2-1=(x+1)(x-1)$$

Comment: Okay. Is there an Algebra list of these axioms(?)?

Comment: There are many monomial relations of that kind, the one I used is the case for $n=2$ of the more general $a^n-b^n=(a-b)(a^{n-1}+\ldots +b^{n-1})$, which you can prove for example by induction on $n$

Comment: What if it was a^2+b^2 instead of minus?

Comment: In that case you can find a factorization in the field of complex numbers, as $a^2+b^2=(a+ib)(a-ib)$

Comment: complex numbers? Oh, my. That's not a simple route to understanding this. I know quadratics can be factored to where you can add the two numbers to get the middle number and multiply them together to get the number on the right. I bring this up because, is there a list, a key of all the ways common equations are factored? Your answer is specific to this type of problem or more general factoring different things?

Answer (score 1):

You can write $$x^4-x^2=x^2(x^2-1)=x^2(x+1)(x-1)$$
where the second is the difference of two squares.

Answer (score 1):

In general case, for a quadratic $ax^2+bx+c$ you can write $$ax^2+bx+c=a(x-x_1)(x-x_2)$$
where $$x_{1,2}=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$

Answer (score 0):

Recall well known identity: $a^2-b^2=(a+b)(a-b)$,
$$\therefore x^4-x^2=(x^2)^2-(x)^2=(x^2+x)(x^2-x)=x(x+1)x(x-1)=x^2(x+1)(x-1)$$